# WiFi Driver/Hardware Issue

Tags: windows-10, dell-inspiron, wifi-driver

I hope you are doing well.

My Issue is related to WiFi driver and hardware.

My laptop specifications are:

Dell Inspiron 5570

Service Tag: GP05ZL2

I installed driver from Dell Website. I encountered blue screen error. I had to force shut down the system. Then I went to BIOS, and turn the WLAN switch OFF and on reboot, Windows booted. But then I restart and again ON the switch and restarted, the windows logo freeze and dots stuck.

Also, when I entered first time after installation of windows(Note that windows was also causing problem, stuck on getting devices ready, I had to turn WiFi switch OFF and it installed). After installation, I restarted, and turned WLAN switch ON, and windows booted, I moved to device manager and looked for Qualcomm 9377 Ac wireless adapter and found it disabled, I enabled it and on enabling, pc got frozen. Then I forced shut down and turned WLAN switch OFF and restarted. Now, when I restarted again(enabled switch ON) and  I  checked WIFI driver it was disabled again. Then I moved to dell drivers on support and installed updated driver in my service tag no list.
And then that blue screen occurred. Scenario now, is I have uninstalled my WiFi driver, it is not showing in devmgmt but still if I switch WLAN on, laptop stuck at Win 10 logo and if I switch OFF, windows boots.

Kindly tell me:

Whether it is a hardware issue/driver issue?
Secondly, I can not run dell diagnostic(on PC), as no WIFI is present.
Preboot diagnostic does  not report any error.
My laptop is in warranty, will it be responsibility of company to facilitate me.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: you can run hardware diagnostics from the bios on a Dell.

Comment: Which driver did you install exactly?  What BSOD error did you receive exactly?  Does provide Windows 10 specific drivers for your device?  Your issues could be caused by drivers, written for an entirely different version of Window, being used on Windows 10.

Comment: I installed Qualcomm 9377 ac wirelessly adapter.

Comment: Yeah, I opened dell.com and it automatically detected my laptop and recommended that driver. I installed it from over there. Now scenerio is that my switch is ON but WiFi device is disabled (from BIOS), if I enable it causes issue, but driver is not showing up in device manager.

Comment: I also ran preboot diagnostics.